# Verify Divergence Theorem (using Spherical Coordinates)

Tags: calculus, surfaces

I'm very used to calculating the flux of a vector field in cartesian coordinates, but I'm still getting tripped up when it comes to spherical or cylindrical coordinates. I was given the vector field:

$\vec{F} = \frac{r\hat{e_r}}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$

and the spherical surface

$r = \sqrt{3}a$.

From what I understand, the vector field is essentially a form of

$\vec{F}(r, \theta, \phi) = <\frac{r}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}}, 0, 0>$

And from this, I would find

$\int \int_S \vec{F}\cdot \hat{n}$

Is that understanding correct? I mainly need help for the surface integrals, but anything to further my understanding is very welcome.

Thank you.

---

My attempt to continue the problem is by first using the unit vector, $\hat{n} = \hat{e_r}$ and taking the dot product of $\vec{F}\cdot \hat{n} = \frac{r}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$.

Using the surface element of constant radius, the surface integral becomes

$\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_0 \frac{r}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}} r^2 sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$

Thus, for $r = \sqrt{3}a$

$ \frac{a^23\sqrt{3}}{2}\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_0 sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$

The result is $6\pi a^2 \sqrt{3}$? I'm not sure if this is right, because when I used the divergence theorem my answer was $4\sqrt{3}\pi a^2 + 3 \pi a^3$.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your understand so far. Can you keep going and solve the surface integral? Note that the unit normal vector on a spherical surface centered at the origin is simply $\hat{n}=\hat{e}_r$.

Comment: Thanks David; I'll try to continue it, but how do you find the unit normal vector so easily? For instance, on the curved part of a cylinder (in cylindrical coordinates), would it simply be $\hat{n} = \hat{e_\rho}$?

Comment: A spherical surface is a surface of constant radius. A normal vector to this surface is a vector perpendicular to it, which is clearly the direction of *increasing* radius. Yes, the normal vector on a cylinder would be just as you guessed. It's completely analogous to $\hat z$ being the normal vector to a surface of contant $z$, such as the $xy$-plane or any plane parallel to it.

Comment: Also, your result $6\sqrt{3}\pi a^2$ is correct. Your calculation using the divergence theorem is wrong.

Comment: Many thanks for everything David. I'll retry my solution for the divergence theorem portion and post an answer if I get it. You've been a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divergence of a vector field $\vec{F}=F_r\hat{e_r}+F_{\theta}\hat{e_{\theta}}+F_{\phi}\hat{e_{\phi}}$ in spherical coordinates is $$\nabla\cdot\vec{F}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2F_r\right)+\frac{1}{r\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\sin{\theta}F_{\theta})+\frac{1}{r\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial F_{\phi}}{\partial\phi}.$$

For the vector field you were given, $\vec{F}=\frac{r\hat{e_r}}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}}$,

$$F_r=\frac{r}{(r^2+a^2)^{1/2}},~~F_{\theta}=F_{\phi}=0$$

$$\implies\nabla\cdot\vec{F}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2F_r\right)$$

Now, before you waste time computing that derivative in the last line above for the divergence, let's set up the integral we're looking to calculate. By the divergence theorem,

$$\iint_{\partial V}\vec{F}\cdot\hat{n}\,dS=\iiint_V\nabla\cdot\vec{F}dV\\
=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{3}a}(\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\,r^2\sin{\theta}\,drd\theta d\phi\\
=\left(\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\right)\left(\int_0^{\pi}\sin{\theta}d\theta\right)\int_0^{\sqrt{3}a}r^2(\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\,dr\\
=4\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{3}a}r^2(\nabla\cdot\vec{F})\,dr\\
=4\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{3}a}r^2\cdot\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2F_r\right)\,dr\\
=4\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{3}a}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2F_r\right)\,dr\\
=4\pi(r^2F_r)\big|_0^{\sqrt{3}a}\\
=4\pi\frac{(\sqrt{3}a)^3}{\sqrt{(\sqrt{3}a)^2+a^2}}\\
=4\pi\frac{3\sqrt{3}a^3}{2a}\\
=6\sqrt{3}\pi a^2.$$

Answer (score -1):

It would make understand better and in detail.
Kindly follow the [link](https://www.cpp.edu/~ajm/materials/delsph.pdf). Then you can solve your problem discussed above.